# I am a Swiss national and want to move to Italy with my Indian husband. What is the process for him acquiring residency?

Tags: residency, indian-citizens, italy

We both live in India at the moment and wedding was in India as well. We want him to come on a tourist visa, not a family reunion visa as that takes a long time. Does it matter from which country the Shengen visa is (like is it a problem if we apply for his visa with the swiss embassy instead of the italian one?) What exactly is the process for him to acquire residency once in Italy and how long does it take  - assuming I have Italian residency by then? Once he applies for residency and has a temporary carta di soggiorno (how long would that take?) can he start working and studying etc?

Im super thankful for any help!

Comment: To travel to Italy, he should apply for a visa from Italy.  He should apply under the freedom-of-movement rules, in which case the visa should be issued free of charge and quickly.  Once in Italy, he should apply for a residence card with the appropriate local office; you as a Portuguese citizen don't have any process to "acquire" residency, though I think you do have to register.

Comment: @phoog I presume you meant "as a Swiss citizen"?

Comment: @MartinBonner apparently so.  I must have been confused by some other question I looked at around the same time as I wrote that comment.